# Why does my re-recorded audio file play back with chipmunk voice?

Tags: c#, wav, naudio, mediaelement, bitrate

I use NAudio 1.72 project to record new audio files and edit existing wav files. I noticed that whenever I open a 172kbps wav file and record part of the file, playback sounds like a chipmunk.

The newly recorded wav files show a bit rate of 128kbps. And I don't find the chipmunk issue with wav files of 128kbps. Does anyone think its a problem because bit rates don't match?

How do I resolve this?

Please note: I am coding in C#, use NAudio project reference to record and edit wav files. I use WPF mediaelement to play back any wav file.

Answer (score -1):

Well, after a bit of exploration, i found this somewhat helpful. Still i am afraid i have regression issues. Still working on making the below strategy work better.

Although below method converts a 176kbps wav file to 128kbps and plays well, the application crashes.

```
    private string OpenMedia(string filename)
    {
        using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(filename))
        {
            int bitrate = reader.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * 8;
            if (bitrate > 128000)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This wav file has a bit rate higher than 128 kbps : " +

    bitrate);

                int channel = reader.WaveFormat.Channels;
                if (channel > 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This wav file was not created in Mono channel : " +

    channel);
                }
                int samplerate = reader.WaveFormat.SampleRate;
                if (samplerate > 8000)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This wav file has a sample rate > 8000 : " + samplerate);
                    var newFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
                    using (var conversionStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(newFormat,

    reader))
                    {
                        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(filename, conversionStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return filename;
    }
```